# How to add a New Page in code to Page-Based Navigation Apple Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a page based app. 1st page shows number of timers with a "add timer" button. When they click that button i want to append a new page with a new timer. Then the user can swipe the left to see all the timers or back to the first page by swiping right to view the count and add another.

Right now I know I can set page based manually in story board and I know I can presentControllerWithNames in my root interface controller but that creates a double load since it first loads the interface controller then executes the presentControllerWithNames.

Any suggestions??

Comment: as far as i know, you can't do that with current sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKInterfaceController has a class method:
 `class func reloadRootControllersWithNames(names: [AnyObject]!, contexts: [AnyObject]!)` to reload all pages.

Just call it in your button's action method:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["theFirstController", "theNewTimerController"], contexts: someContexts)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I remember seeing this method on another question but I guess I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to check how many timers the user has and make that many pages initially when the app loads without reloading in the awakeWithContext which causes the loading activity icon to appear twice?

Comment: Louis Zhu: How to halt the hiding the back button after this. I want to go its parent interfaceViewController.